# Trying to xor file content, but it won't cast as int

Tags: python

I have a text file. The text file contains 1's and 0's. What I want to do is:

1. Read first 256bit block
2. xor with second 256bit block
3. print
4. xor that with the next 256bit block
5. etc

To accomplish that I wrote this quick script:

```
with open("binary.txt", "rb") as f:
    bits = f.read(256)
    bits = '0b' + bits
    while bits != "":
        #print bits
        tempstore = bits
        bits = f.read(256)
        bits = '0b' + bits
        print bin(int(tempstore) ^ int(bits))
```

I verified that the values `bits` and `tempstore` are in the format `0x010001...`. I tried using `bin(tempstore) ^ bin(bits)` instead of `int`, or completely leaving it out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would you provide (a sample of) binary.txt so we can test your code please. You should be able to convert binary to an integer by giving the base to the `int()` function. Sample usage: `int("10010111101",2)` returns `1213`. You will have to remove the "0x" from each string to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a base to the `int` function to read an integer that is written in different bases. The default is `10` but to read a binary number you just need to call `int(string, 2)`. Note that starting the string with `"0b"` is strictly optional: `int("1011", 2) == int("0b1101",2) == 13` but that the base *isn't* optional unless your string is a valid representation of a base 10 integer.

Given all that working (python2) code would look something roughly like this:

```
with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:
    read_string = f.read(256)
    bits = int(read_string, 2)

    while True:
        read_string = f.read(256)
        if read_string == "":
            break
        bits = bits ^ int(read_string, 2)

        print bin(bits)
```

Note that the behaviour will be somewhat strange if the number of characters in the file isn't devisable by 256. The last string read will be shorter than the others (and will effectively get padded with zeroes) which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not a Python programmer but I see a lot of problems there:

1) An INTEGER is NOT a sequence of 256 bits (0 and 1), but a sequence of 32 bits.

2) You are not converting the read BITS correctly. You don´t have to put '0b' 
since your are creating a new string, just starting with '0b'.

3) You cannot convert a binary string to Integer just using INT(). Probably, you must utilize a routine to Binary2Byte

4) Probably you must XOR an 8-bits, 32-bits, or 64-bits each time - not a number of 256 bits.

Comment: This is basically all wrong. In python an integer is automatically converted to a bignum if required so their size is practically unbounded (obviously memory constraints have cause issues with ridiculous numbers but 255 bits is fine). For example the function `int("1"*256,2)` correctly returns a very large number (about 1.2x10^77 in decimal). You can in fact bitwise XOR these large numbers absolutely fine as the [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) states.